# How to perform a calculation involving values from multiple rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to compute a value in a DataFrame at time t which involves values from times t and t-1. In straight Python, I would zip together two length n-1 fraagments of the list, like so:

```
>>> x = [random.random() for _ in range(10)]
>>> x
[0.09154030286701986, 0.7695293091436095, 0.003169617773302602, 0.18746852585939167, 0.16382872408720617, 0.951061080433954, 0.2880246300316386, 0.2585431567171105, 0.40819533123361884, 0.9482919441157496]
>>> [(a - b) for (a, b) in zip(x[:-1], x[1:])]
[-0.6779890062765896, 0.7663596913703069, -0.18429890808608906, 0.023639801772185498, -0.7872323563467478, 0.6630364504023154, 0.029481473314528106, -0.14965217451650836, -0.5400966128821307]
```

then handle the edge cases as appropriate.

Is there a similar idiom using DataFrames?

Let me add that this obvious (to me) analog doesn't do what I'd expect it to:

```
In [321]: x
Out[321]: 
         r1        r2
0 -1.059815 -1.159293
1  2.393336  0.458090
2  0.055295  1.389807
3 -0.102741 -0.126111
4  1.242702 -1.846763
5 -0.115352 -0.051099
6 -1.676272  1.117046
7 -0.404109  0.139790

In [322]: x["r1"][:-1] - x["r2"][1:]
Out[322]: 
0         NaN
1    1.935245
2   -1.334512
3    0.023370
4    3.089465
5   -0.064253
6   -2.793318
7         NaN
dtype: float64
```

I expected the result of -1.059815 - 0.458090 to be in the first position, not NaN.

```
In [325]: [a-b for (a, b) in zip(list(x["r1"])[:-1], list(x["r2"])[1:])]
Out[325]: 
[-1.5179054299355403,
 1.0035286021021981,
 0.1814061862111446,
 1.7440218133011343,
 1.2938016423931689,
 -1.2323982743162547,
 -1.8160616387411936]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `shift`, which as the name implies shifts values up/down the index.

Your approach doesn't work because pandas aligns by index.  So when you add subsets of the rows, they will be aligned back to where they started because the index isn't changed.

```
In [266]: x['r1'] - x['r2'].shift(-1)
Out[266]: 
0   -1.517905
1    1.003529
2    0.181406
3    1.744022
4    1.293801
5   -1.232398
6   -1.816062
7         NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. The APIs for these objects are enormous compared to the basic Python data structures that it creates a pretty high barrier to adoption. It looks like Series instances have 214 public attributes. In contrast, a Python list has 9.